# Check which event fired the function with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How can I check which event called my function on JavaScript with jQuery?

Like I have:

```
var mycall= function() { 
    alert('Which Witch is Which?');
}

$(window).load(mycall);
$(window).resize(mycall);
```

I understand that I could pass a parameter to the function, still I'm interested in a way to do this without passing any parameters.

Comment: *"I understand that i could pass a parameter to the function, still i'm interested in a way to do this without passing any parameters."* - And why would that be? So you know the solution, but you want a more complicated way to achieve the same thing?  Seems backwards to me, go with simple, well understood methods to accomplish simple, well understood problems.

Comment: let's say i have a code which i use in 15 websites, i'd rather change only one JS then all the calls i made to that JS :)

also out of pure curiosity...

Comment: @EdS. He just wants to know if there is some kind of analog to `event.target`. I don't know of one, but I admit it would be a nice thing to have.

Comment: What you call "pass a parameter" is actually "declare named parametr". Actual parametrs are passed by calling code (jQuery), so you'll have params anyway. They could be accessed w/o declaration using `arguments` like I wrote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an event to the function args and then `event.type` will give tell which event is triggered. See below,

```
var mycall= function(e) { 
    alert(e.type);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Use the [`type` property](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/) in the `event` object:

```
var mycall = function(e) { 
  alert(e.type);
};
```

Comment: @SKS and he even wrote an extra space between `mycall=`

Comment: @ajax333221 but have 2 less spaces before `alert`. So they type with 1/39 char per sec :-D